# How to deal with database pagination when a row in between can be deleted by user action?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, pagination

I am stuck in a situation. I hope I get a solution here. I am using paging to show some data on user profile page.

Using a basic paging to do so:

```
public Page list(Query query, int pageNo, int perPage) {

    int totalResults = query.list().size();

    int firstResult = (pageNo - 1) * perPage;
    query.setFirstResult(firstResult);
    query.setMaxResults(perPage);
    List resultList = query.list();
    return new Page(resultList, perPage, pageNo, totalResults);
}
```

Page class constructor:

```
public Page(List resultList, int pageSize, int page, int totalResults)   {
    this.resultList = resultList;
    this.pageSize = pageSize;
    this.page = page;
    this.totalResults = totalResults;
    this.totalPages = (totalResults - 1) / pageSize + 1;
}
```

Now if the results where to displayed normally without any deletion in between  this would work fine. But a user can remove items from his action list.

Lets have the situation. Say there were `totalResults` - 17, `perPage` - 6 and `totalPages` - 3.

Now in the first page he deletes 2 items which leaves to total of 15 results and the row id which was to be in 2nd page has shifted to 9 instead of 7 (as two items are no there and the total result is now 15).

I hope the situation is clear. Now this intermediate shifting is not required.

I was thinking of implementing it as `remainingItems` but again I am bit confused in that. Remaining item would always be dependent on the `pageNo` and `perPage` and independent of the `totalResult` (since total result gets decreased in between). I cannot use last n rows here also as the row count will again decrease shifting my desired result.

I also do not want to keep too many parameter in the method. For example - lets say I pass the `toSatrtWith` id in the parameter and fetch `perPage` number of rows from there I may get the desired thing. But I want a more elegant solution.

Comment: Big question takes some users into confusion :), I am not getting one thing hope you clear it. When a user deletes any number of items then you must be again calculating `totalResults`, `totalPages` by calling `list()` then why you need to worry about deletion and insertion of rows, it will be recalculated every time, right? explain your problem in short.

Comment: say there are 13 results, page1-(6), page2-(6), page3-(1). When on page2 user deleted something, db count becomes 12(not 13) so on fetching the 3rd page totalResult is 12 and the last result cannot be fetched now on third page. This happened because of recalculation of the totalResult.

Comment: As @Amogh suggested, the simplest solution is to requery for each deleted row.

Comment: @gknicker no but I got what OP wants to say, consider an view where he is displaying pages as 1,2,3 having link to see the result on that page now as he commented what if another user deletes last record and current user clicks on 3 page..am I correct?

Comment: @amogh user is same (another user or same user - same thing). Yes, the result which was to be shown on 3rd page has gone away because of basic pagination calculations.

Comment: @NihalSharma well delete operation by same user is not a big deal because on delete operation you can recalculate all the things, in your example if delete is perform on page 2 then it will recalculate and total pages will become 2. problem is with when when other user delete.

Comment: You can recalculate every time a user switches between pages, so if someone else deleted anything and impacted the results - you can show the user whatever results are NOW relevant - regradles of what you were PLANNING to show before. For example, if user was on page 2, goes to page 3, but the results for page 3 are no longer than - show page 2 again, but let the user understand that "something happend".

Comment: Yes solution by @oferLando is nice, as he said you can display a message to user so that he can come to know when he navigate to last page according to your example.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Short answer:  Remember "where you left off" rather than computing the location.

Long answer:  See my blog on why "Pagination via LIMIT and OFFSET is evil":  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination .  (You are doing the PHP equivalent of using LIMIT and OFFSET, so the blog applies.)

The url for the [Next] would include the `id` of the last item on this page, then use `WHERE id > $id` when building the next page.  (Or `id` of the first item off this page, then `WHERE id >= $id`.  This slight difference has a minor effect when a row is inserted between the two.)  Also have this in the SQL:  `ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 10`.  It will fetch only 10 rows, regardless of which page.  Without this trick, you are fetching all the rows for all the pages before the current one.

[Prev] page is similar, but with a flag saying to go backwards (`ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10`).

[First] is probably best done by not specifying id; then the code will say "Oh, I should build the first page."

[Last] could include a flag for Last or `id=-1` or whatever -- then use  something like `ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10` in the SQL.

Without this technique, a row that is deleted or inserted before the current page causes the list to be shifted off by one item (forward or backward), hence, the user misses (bad?) a row or gets a row duplicated (just annoying).

Comment: My solution also deals with the related problem of a newly-INSERTed item.

Comment: Yeah, true. I also cannot think of anything other than sending last id of the fetched records on the ui and then querying n items beyond the last id. But do you think it is an elegant solution and also for the first page since the id is not available we have do the crude way.? Can you please mention these points in the answer as well (just in short)? Thanks

Comment: Done.  Need anything else?

Comment: @RickJames how to deals with new inserted row. when pagination is ongoing in N-page, for example, is 3th page, then there is new inserted in 1st page, how to show that new data to user. 
nb. we have state that user curently request 3th page

Comment: @Muklas - Using `OFFSET` leads to subtle bugs.  If you are on the 3rd page of 10 rows each, there are 20 rows "before" your page.  If a row is inserted back there, now there are 21 rows.  With `OFFSET`, [Prev] would ask for rows 21-30, skipping over a row.  WIth "go back 10 rows", you would get 22-31 and not skip any.  Etc.

Comment: This solution does not work when we UUIDs for identifiers. And there are many reasons to use UUIDs over auto_incremented integers (for one, if you accidentally enter the wrong table name in a `DELETE WHERE id IN...` statement, nothing will be deleted). That being said, you'll need a different field that is order-able. I think a good choice is always having a `created_time` which is of type `TIMESTAMP`. This is always guaranteed to be ordered, and is generated on the Database, so it should be available across all app servers connected to that DB.

Answer (score 1):

I came across the exact same problem.

My solutions was to process each page in reverse order, i.e., I start by the last page, then the second last, all the way to the first page. In this way even if I delete some rows in page N+1, this won't change anything in page N (or N-1,N-2,..,1).

Comment: This is really good idea for deletes. However there is a chance of duplicates / empty pages.