# How to deal with adding and removing items in pagination (infinite scroll)

Tags: javascript, rest, pagination, infinite-scroll

I have REST API endpoint that accepts `page`, `limit` (page size) and returns (for simplicity) sorted letters of alphabet (A, B, C, ... Z). Example call of this endpoint is:

```js
let items = await api.items.get({ page: 0, size: 3 })
// items = ["A", "B", "C"]
```

Now let's say I have implemented infinite scroll and when user scrolls at the of the area, I want to load another 3 items:

```js
const newItems = await api.items.get({ page: 1, size: 3 })
items = [...items, ...newItems]
// items = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]
```

Everything is fine, however what if user deletes some items, eg. "B" and "D"?

```
// items = ["A", "C", "E", "F"]
```

How can I fetch another page of 3 items from correct offset?

```
const newItems = await api.items.get({ page: 2, size: 3 })
items = [...items, ...newItems]
// items = ["A", "C", "E", "F", "I", "J", "K"] - "G" and "H" has been skipped
```

Are there any common techniques for this? Unfortunately, I can't modify the API, so I have to use `page` and `size` only.

Comment: same situation: (java) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28736208/how-to-deal-with-database-pagination-when-a-row-in-between-can-be-deleted-by-use (ruby on rails) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44931345/infinite-scrolling-with-will-paginate-issue-removing-element unfortunately, best solutions require modification of the API.